# How do I unpack this nested object?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, list-comprehension, inspect, iterable-unpacking

Inside a function, I want to print, for all function parameters, "parameter_name=value"

And I want to get the data from inspect.getfullargspec()[0:4:3], which seems to return a tuple of lists with variable names, and variable values.

```
class someclass(object):
def someFunction(self,
                    var1=10000,
                    varname=[4000,1],
                    somethin=0.1,
                    blabla = 0.4,
                    this="gfjgf"):   
    import inspect
    [print(arg,"=",value,"\n") for j in inspect.getfullargspec(self.someFunction)[0:4:3] for arg,value in zip(j)]
```

inspect.getfullargspec(self.someFunction)[0] is a list of strings with the variable names

inspect.getfullargspec(self.someFunction)[3] is a tuple of the variable values

I expect this output:

```
var1=10000
varname=[4000,1]
somethin=0.1
blabla = 0.4
this=gfjgf
```

but I get random garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if all parameters are keywords:

```py
for arg,name in zip(self.someFunction.__code__.co_varnames[1:], self.someFunction.__defaults__[1:]):
    print(arg, "=", name)
```

The [1:] is for slicing away the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tears, this is the simplest way I found, but doesn't seems very pythonic:

```
parameters=inspect.getfullargspec(self.someFunction)
[print(var,"==", value)  for var , value in zip( list(parameters[0][1:]) ,list(parameters[3]))]
```

I can't believe I wasted an hour to write that single line, and is still awful.